# In jQuery, how do you select textbox that has a value of multiple spaces?

Tags: jquery

I need to select such textboxes so as to validate required field. How do I go about doing it? Seems I can use a if statement, but I'm not sure how to implement.

I wrote the following required field validator to test for empty textboxes, but cannot detect textboxes with multiple spaces. Am I not doing validation the correct way? Should I be using a plugin for validation?

```
function validate()
        {
            $('.LoginFormBodyRightColumn input:text[value!=""]').next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').hide();
            $('.LoginFormBodyRightColumn input:text[value=""]').next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').show();
            $('.LoginFormBodyRightColumn input:password[value!=""]').next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').hide();
            $('.LoginFormBodyRightColumn input:password[value=""]').next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').show();


        }
```

It seems to me a if statement has no place in jQuery, because in jQuery you select something and then perform something on the selector. A if statement involving selectors is meaningless.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please can you explain more and show us an example of code?

Comment: You can write `span.RequiredValidator` instead of `span[class*="RequiredValidator"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate()
        {
         $('.LoginFormBodyRightColumn input:text,.LoginFormBodyRightColumn input:password,').each(function(){
         if($.trim($(this).val())==="")
         $(this).next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').show();
         else
         $(this).next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').hide();
         });
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

AS I understand your problem try this..

```
<input class="LoginFormBodyRightColumn" type="text" />
<span class="RequiredValidator">*</span>
<input class="LoginFormBodyRightColumn" type="password" />
<span class="RequiredValidator">*</span>

<script >
  $("input").each(function(){
  var str=$(this).val();

  if(str=='')
      $(this).next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').show();
  else
      $(this).next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').hide();
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try getting the values of all your inputs and validate with code not whith jquery selectors. Use the jquery trim function to remove whitespaces.

```
function validate( jQueryFormSelector )
{
  var inputs = $(jQueryFormSelector).find('input');
  inputs.each( function (i,el) {
    if ( $.trim( $(el).val() ) == '' )
    {
      $(el).next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').show();
    }
    else
    {
      $(el).next('span[class*="RequiredValidator"]').hide();
    }
  });

}
```